# Would a function (with no arguments) calling itself indefinitely cause a memory error in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider the following block of pseudo-code:

```
async function  someFunction(){
    if (condition is met){
        ...
        ...
        ...
        someFunction();
    }
    else{
        ...
        ...
        ...
        someOtherFunction();
    }
}
```

Would every time that you call `someFunction()` cause memory to be allocated for it and still keep the `someFunction()` that made the call in memory or is JavaScript smart enough to realise that once `someFunction()` calls itself the function that did the calling is no longer needed and will not need to stay in memory. Notice how `someFunction()` does not take any arguments. I believe if it did take arguments then it would always need to be saved in memory, but I could be wrong.

If the above implementation still saves every function call in memory then what would the correct thing to do be. Would it be to `return someFunction()` in the `if` block?

Comment: _Would every time that you call someFunction() cause memory to be allocated for it and still keep the someFunction() that made the call in memory_ - Yes, that is correct.

Comment: _If the above implementation still saves every function call in memory then what would the correct thing to do be. Would it be to return someFunction() in the if block?_ - When a functions calls itself, it is known as recursion and you will have to stop the recursion at some point otherwise you will overflow the call stack. You could stop the recursion by using a condition that when evaluates to true, returns a value instead of making another recursive call.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was wondering if there is a way to keep the recursive aspect, but delete the caller function from memory as soon as it calls itself again. The ```someFunction()``` does not need to eventually evaluate to anything.

Comment: Yes. This is called a stack overflow. Use a loop instead if you expect there to be a lot of nested calls while the condition is met.

Comment: Unfortunately js engines still don't implement tail call optimisations.

Comment: If you post your real code, we can offer you specific alternative ways to code this that don't use recursion.  With your posted pseudo-code, we can't see the actual problem here so it would take a ridiculously long answer to cover all the possible solutions.  Usually, the solution is to use a loop like a `while` loop or a `for` loop so there's no stack buildup just to execute the same code again.